# Function varchar to time conversion(hh:mm:ss) failed

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertTimeToHH:MM:SS] 
(
    @P_Value NVARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(50)=''
DECLARE @Result1 NVARCHAR(50)=''
IF @P_Value !=''
BEGIN
    SET @Result = '(SELECT CONVERT(@P_Value,GETDATE(),108) as [hh:mm:ss])';
    RETURN @Result 
END
set @Result1='enter some value'

RETURN @Result1

END 


input: select [dbo].[ConvertTimeToHH:MM:SS] ('14')
output: the output shall be 14:00:00
input:select [dbo].[ConvertTimeToHH:MM:SS] ('14:3')
output: shall be 14:03:00
```

Select convert doesn't execute. What's wrong with this code please. When I execute this function I get output as:

(SELECT CONVERT(@P_Value,GETDATE(),108) as [hh:mm:ss])

Comment: perhaps consider timefromparts()   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/timefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: You're returning a string from you function, a string with SQL inside it? Did you actually want to run the select, as opposed to returning it as a string? Do you want this `SET @Result = (SELECT CONVERT(@P_Value,GETDATE(),108) as [hh:mm:ss]);`

Comment: @Dale K don't have much knowledge in sql functions . just tried this function but failed.

Comment: Check some tutorials, bit fundamentally don't quote queries you want to run, that just makes a string.

Comment: @Dale K if i dont quote i get error like "incorrect systax error ""@p_value".expecting DOUBLE,ID,NATIONAL,or QUOTED ID.

Comment: Besides the point DaleK makes, the first argument of `CONVERT` is the datatype you want to convert to. `CONVERT('14', GETDATE(), 108)` doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: I honestly haven't the faintest idea what this function is trying to achieve. The `CONVERT` makes no sense as mentioned, and if it did you wouldn't need another function for it, you could just call it directly wherever you need it. It sounds like you might just want `CONVERT(datetime, NULLIF(YourValue, ''), 108)`

Answer (score 0):

This will get it done, you will need to be responsible for validation. Assumption here is that data will have some format of `nn:nn:nn`. Anything outside of that, you'll need to rethink your solution.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertTimeToHH:MM:SS] 
(
    @P_Value NVARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
BEGIN

IF @P_Value = ''
BEGIN
    RETURN 'enter some value'
END

DECLARE @hour VARCHAR(2) = ''
    , @min VARCHAR(2) = ''
    , @sec VARCHAR(2) = ''
    , @index INT

DECLARE @tmp VARCHAR(10)
    , @result VARCHAR(10);

SELECT @index = CHARINDEX(':', @P_Value)

-- only hour number is present
IF @index = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @hour = @P_Value;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- at least hour and minute is present
    SET @hour = LEFT(@P_Value, @index - 1);
    set @tmp = RIGHT(@P_Value, LEN(@P_Value) - @index);

    -- check if seconds is present
    SELECT @index = CHARINDEX(':', @tmp);

    IF @index = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @min = @tmp
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @min = LEFT(@tmp, @index - 1);
        SET @sec = RIGHT(@tmp, LEN(@tmp) - @index);
    END
END

SELECT @result = CONCAT(FORMAT(CAST(@hour AS INT), '00'), ':', FORMAT(CAST(@min AS INT), '00'), ':', FORMAT(CASt(@sec AS INT), '00'));
RETURN @result;

END 
GO
```

Results:

```
select [dbo].[ConvertTimeToHH:MM:SS] ('14')
select [dbo].[ConvertTimeToHH:MM:SS] ('1')
select [dbo].[ConvertTimeToHH:MM:SS] ('1:1')
select [dbo].[ConvertTimeToHH:MM:SS] ('1:1:1')


---------
14:00:00

---------
01:00:00

---------
01:01:00

---------
01:01:01
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.could you please look into another question and answer if you have time.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027390/sql-function-to-convert-hhmm-to-decimal-hours