# SQL function to convert hh:mm to decimal hours

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertHHMMToDecimal] 
    (@P_Value NVARCHAR(50))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @V_Results NVARCHAR(50)

    // I have to check if the @P_Value contains ":"
    // then only I will go for conversion

END
```

If data has `':'` then the conversion can take minutes to hours to complete.

Example:

Input file has cumulative hours as `123:6`, then the value as  123+(6\60*100)=123+.1 =123.1. If it is decimal then rounding it to 2 digits. If it is invalid or blank then preserving the same input value

Comment: `123:6` is not `HH:MM`... It has 1 too many digits for the hours, and 1 too few for the minutes.

Comment: but as per my requirement the hours and minutes are coming in this format only.

Comment: your requirement smells....

Comment: If :6 is SIX minutes , then I assume :15 is FIFTEEN ... What would :1 or :10 be ?

Comment: just imagine 12:30 .how we can convert that into decimal hours?

Comment: What "format only"? Your question states that the format is `hh:mm` but then you give only *one* example and that example contradicts the format you say you have.

Comment: *"just imagine 12:30 .how we can convert that into decimal hours?"* Hint: `DATEPART`

Comment: DATEPART returns only INT value.But i need result in the form of decimal hours

Comment: You already have the formula to do that `123+(6\60*100)=123+.1` thought I have no idea why you need to  `* 100`. Anyway, what is the actual problem you are facing ?

Comment: im facing problm in writing this sql function..I am new just trying to practice sql functions

Comment: just need solution. dont have experince in writing sql function

Comment: Review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Are we creating multiple accounts to ask the same question in slightly different ways now? [SQL Function to check in column is present in HH:MM then convert HH:MM to decimal hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74023778)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Perhaps two students from the same class both trying to get someone else to do their homework. It saddens me to see instructors issuing assignments that teach bad design so early in their education.

Answer (score -3):

Use `charindex()`

```
IF CHARINDEX(‘:’, @P_Value) > 0
BEGIN
…
END
```